# how to use config-vars in seajs

Tags: javascript, cmd

i want to define a global variable for module in seajs:

i have many jsp pages. By making some config in jap, i can share one module to many jsp:

```
seajs.config({
    vars: {
        'a': 'name1',
        'b': 'name2'
    }
});
```

in my module:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    console.log(seajs.data.vars.a); //name1
    console.log(seajs.data.vars.b); //name2
});
```

i know it works, but it is not correct using like this, is there any way to transfer a global variable to each js module but not just define a global variable directly in jsp?

Comment: Since seajs nor sea.js is a tag here, linking to it may be of some help.

Comment: i don't have permission to create a new tag yet >3<

Answer (score -1):

vars config allways be used load different module like:

```
require('lib/{a}.js');
```

if you want to config some variable  to modules,you can define a module like:

```
define(function(require, exports, module){exports.a='xx';exports.b='xxx';});
```

this module just store config values